# Using intervention/image for upload /resizing with Laravel API

Tags: mysql, laravel, intervention

I am trying to upload an image to the database with a path created in public (i.e., uploads/images) but unfortunately, it is not displaying any error, and the image is not uploaded or saved to the directory.

**Controller**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Image;

class ImagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('image');
    }

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'images' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('images');
        $input['imagename'] = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/images');
        $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($destinationPath . '/' . $input['imagename']);

        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);
        $this->postImage->add($input);

        if (!empty($input['imagename'])) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $input['imagename']->toArray()
            ]);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::post('upload', 'ImagesController@upload');
```

**Model**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['image'];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, check if you have the correct permissions. What is the error ? or there is no error ?. check if the image is being saving in another directory

Comment: Can you please replace this `$input['imagename']` with `$filename` and check ?

Comment: In your postman request you should specify the **images** property and attach the file there, which i can't see on your screenshot. Then first of all if you have not created a uploads/images directory in your public folder, then create it and set read write permissions. Then try again

Comment: @MarcoFeregrino it is not saved to any directory

Comment: @ViperTecPro I have done all that and still not saving.

Comment: @user3581438 how do I specify that and create permission. I have created uploads/images in the public folder. I did

Comment: Can you please try saving static data to the image say hello.jpg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adopt this style then run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Also, change your controller to this

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {

        $img = new Image();

        $validation = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'string',
            'image' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,gif,webp|max:2048'
        ]);
        $file      = $validation['image']; // get the validated file
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename  = 'mm-image-' . time() . '.' . $extension;
        $path      = $file->storeAs('/uploads/images', $filename);
        $img->image = $request->image;
        $img->title = $path;

        dd($img);


            if (!empty($img)){
                return response()([
                    'success' => true,
                    'data' => $img->toArray()
                ]);;

            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works but I have another issue. Please, how do I retrieve the saved image and create a merging copy with another image already saved

Answer (score 1):

Before saving image file to directory ensure you haved added **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in your `<form>` tag.

Chek you have change public path from file system situated at **C:\xampp\htdocs\isp\config\filesystems.php**.
 Now check my following code to get idea and modify your code according to this.

```
    public function site(Request $request)
   {  


        if ($request->hasFile('imagename')) {
            $image = $request->file('imagename');
            $filename = 'image'.rand(1,5) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('uploads/image/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image)->save($location);
        }
        Session::flash('flash_message_success', 'Site profile updated successfully');
        return redirect()->route('site');


   }
```

I think you have give an extra **/** in **public_path()** function. Correct it. and alsow change your validation parameters `'images' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,JPEG,PNG,JPG,GIF,SVG|max:2048',`

Hope that any of condition will be filled up and you will be succeeded

Comment: Please, I don't seem to understand the code. My fieldname is images. Where is post, site_id, logo? Where would I add this enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: I modified the answer by deleting unwanted code. Check it.

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class &#039;App\Http\Controllers\Session&#039; not found in file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/flavourvotes/Server/app/Http/Controllers/ImagesController.php on line 45

Comment: Not working, not displaying error but not saving image to the directory specified and not also saving to the database